# Storing data into list with class

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have the following class:

```
public class EmailData
{
    public string FirstName{ set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
    public string Location{ set; get; }
}
```

I then did the following but was not working properly:

```
List<EmailData> lstemail = new List<EmailData>(); 
lstemail.Add("JOhn","Smith","Los Angeles");
```

I get a message that says no overload for method takes 3 arguments.

Comment: What error message did you receive?

Comment: OMG u guys are fast....

Comment: I don't really get the downvotes, to be honest.

Comment: @Morpheus: Someone posts a question. What we see: `On your marks, get set, go!`

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett just when i was about to type the answer i do a refresh pop 5 answers already!

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Same, except mine was 8 answers.

Comment: @Christopher Estep This is the 3rd question i missed out. I upvoted every answer because everyone responded in a jiffy

Comment: @Christopher Yeah I down-voted because of the incorrect uppercase in "JOhn".

Comment: @Ugo You cost a guy reputation because of a sticky shift key? Wow, I thought *I* was pedantic!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you want to instantiate and add in the same line, you'd have to do something like this:

```
lstemail.Add(new EmailData { FirstName = "JOhn", LastName = "Smith", Location = "Los Angeles" });
```

or just instantiate the object prior, and add it directly in:

```
EmailData data = new EmailData();
data.FirstName = "JOhn";
data.LastName = "Smith";
data.Location = "Los Angeles"

lstemail.Add(data);
```

Comment: How can I read the data from the list once I add some data into the list. Consider I have added three records.

Comment: Random user - add a foreach loop, and iterate over your list

Answer (score 87):

You need to add an instance of the class:

```
lstemail.Add(new EmailData { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", Location = "Los Angeles"});
```

I would recommend adding a constructor to your class, however:

```
public class EmailData
{
    public EmailData(string firstName, string lastName, string location)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Location = location;
    }
    public string FirstName{ set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
    public string Location{ set; get; }
}
```

This would allow you to write the addition to your list using the constructor:

```
lstemail.Add(new EmailData("John", "Smith", "Los Angeles"));
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that at all!  Why not simply use the Object Initialization syntax!?!?!?  Unless you have logic in the constructor, or need to force certain parameters to be set, I wouldn't add a constructor.

Comment: @JohnBubriski It's unlikely that there is a valid meaning for an `EmailData` class (in this instance) without a name or location.  Using a default constructor would allow a user to inadvertently create a class that is in an invalid state.  Whenever possible, it's ALWAYS a good idea to force constructors to include all required data to initialize the object into a meaningful state, as this will prevent errors from occurring over time.

Comment: @JohnBubriski Also for the cases where you want to make your objects immutable it's a way to avoid a public setter.

Comment: @R0MANARMY Sure, but that's a specific piece of functionality.

Comment: @JohnBubriski Yes, it is.  You asked why not use object initialization syntax, Reed and I gave you two reasons.  Admittedly his is much better than mine.

Comment: Conversely, not having a default constructor means you can't select instances of EmailData with some LINQ queries.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni How so?  This is not an issue with LINQ to Objects, but does require you to be explicit about using the constructor...

Answer (score 31):

You need to new up an instance of EmailData and then add that:

```
var data = new EmailData { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", Location = "LA" };

List<EmailData> listemail = new List<EmailData>();
listemail.Add(data);
```

If you want to able to do:

```
listemail.Add("JOhn","Smith","Los Angeles");
```

you can create your own custom list, by specializing System.Collections.Generic.List and implementing your own Add method, more or less like this:

```
public class EmailList : List<EmailData>
{
    public void Add(string firstName, string lastName, string location)
    {
        var data = new EmailData 
                   { 
                       FirstName = firstName, 
                       LastName = lastName,
                       Location = location
                   };
        this.Add(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

One way(in one line) to do it is like this:

```
listemail.Add(new EmailData {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", Location = "Los Angeles"});
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to create an instance of the class to add:

```
lstemail.Add(new EmailData
                 {
                     FirstName = "JOhn",
                     LastName = "Smith",
                     Location = "Los Angeles"
                 });
```

See [How to: Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)

---

Alternatively you could declare a constructor for you `EmailData` object and use that to create the instance.

Answer (score 8):

You're not adding a new instance of the class to the list. Try this:

```
lstemail.Add(new EmailData { FirstName="John", LastName="Smith", Location="Los Angeles" });`
```

`List` is a generic class. When you specify a `List<EmailData>`, the `Add` method is expecting an object that's of type `EmailData`. The example above, expressed in more verbose syntax, would be:

```
EmailData data = new EmailData();
data.FirstName="John";
data.LastName="Smith;
data.Location = "Los Angeles";
lstemail.Add(data);
```

Answer (score 8):

You are attempting to call

```
List<EmailData>.Add(string,string,string)
```

. Try this:

```
lstemail.add(new EmailData{ FirstName="John", LastName="Smith", Location="Los Angeles"});
```

Answer (score 6):

How do you expect `List<EmailData>.Add` to know how to turn three `string`s into an instance of `EmailData`? You're expecting too much of the Framework. There is no overload of `List<T>.Add` that takes in three string parameters. In fact, the only overload of `List<T>.Add` takes in a `T`. Therefore, you have to create an instance of `EmailData` and pass that to `List<T>.Add`. That is what the above code does.

Try:

```
lstemail.Add(new EmailData {
    FirstName = "JOhn", 
    LastName = "Smith",
    Location = "Los Angeles"
});
```

This uses the C# object initialization syntax. Alternatively, you can add a constructor to your class

```
public EmailData(string firstName, string lastName, string location) {
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
    this.Location = location;
}
```

Then:

```
lstemail.Add(new EmailData("JOhn", "Smith", "Los Angeles"));
```

Answer (score 6):

This line is your problem:

```
lstemail.Add("JOhn","Smith","Los Angeles");
```

There is no direct cast from 3 strings to your custom class.  The compiler has no way of figuring out what you're trying to do with this line.  You need to `Add()` an instance of the class to `lstemail`:

```
lstemail.Add(new EmailData { FirstName = "JOhn", LastName = "Smith", Location = "Los Angeles" });
```

Comment: The second line won't compile, either - need to specify the property names in an object initializer...

Comment: +0.5 Good explanation, but that's not how the C# object-initialization syntax works. See answers above. :)

Comment: D'oh!  That'll teach me to free-hand code without testing it :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's the extension method version:

```
public static class ListOfEmailDataExtension
{
    public static void Add(this List<EmailData> list, 
        string firstName, string lastName, string location)
    {
        if (null == list)
            throw new NullReferenceException();

        var emailData = new EmailData
                            {
                                FirstName = firstName, 
                                LastName = lastName, 
                                Location = location
                            };
        list.Add(emailData);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<EmailData> myList = new List<EmailData>();
myList.Add("Ron", "Klein", "Israel");
```

Comment: No need of the null check - list.Add will throw it anyway.

Comment: @Sunny, I agree, but I still think it's a better practice to check for null value before executing additional code.

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to create the list with some elements to start with:

```
var emailList = new List<EmailData>
{
   new EmailData { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Location = "Moscow" },
   new EmailData {.......}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  public IEnumerable<CustInfo> SaveCustdata(CustInfo cust)
        {
            try
            {
                var customerinfo = new CustInfo
                {
                    Name = cust.Name,
                    AccountNo = cust.AccountNo,
                    Address = cust.Address
                };
                List<CustInfo> custlist = new List<CustInfo>();
                custlist.Add(customerinfo);
                return custlist;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EmailData clsEmailData = new EmailData();
List<EmailData> lstemail = new List<EmailData>(); 

clsEmailData.FirstName="JOhn";
clsEmailData.LastName ="Smith";
clsEmailData.Location ="Los Angeles"

lstemail.add(clsEmailData);
```

Comment: Sorry because i didn't understand ur question meaning will u pls elaborate ur question so i can help?                                                                            Thanks