# Storing Class Data In A List

Tags: c#, list

Well I have a class like this and I want to store in a list which is defined as a static variable. I was following the reference here: [Storing data into list with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391885/storing-data-into-list-with-class)

```
public class Faculty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public string[] subInterest = new string[4];
}
```

However when I try to initialize the list as follows I have problem with the array part:    ***Invalid initializer member declarator***

```
SaveDirectory.list_of_faculty.Add(
    new Faculty
    {
        Name = txtTeachherName.Text,
        Dept = cmbDepts.Items.CurrentItem.ToString(),
        subInterest[0] = "HELLO"
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to:

```
subInterest[0] = "HELLO"
```

You can not partially initialize an array in Object Initializer, either it is full or nothing, You can do:

```
subInterest = new string[]{"HELLO"}
```

**But,** this will leave the array `subInterest` with size `1`, not as size `4`, as you have defined in your class. To get the array of same size you can do:

```
subInterest = new string[]{"HELLO",null,null,null}
```

Another option is to use `List<string>` instead of an Array. You can initialize it with value and later you can add items to it.

Modify your class like:

```
public class Faculty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public List<string> subInterest;
}
```

and then:

```
new Faculty
{
    Name = txtTeachherName.Text,
    Dept = cmbDepts.Items.CurrentItem.ToString(),
    subInterest = new List<string>(){"HELLO"}
};
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Could you please point out to the mistake, so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reach in to your object and initialize members of an array that it holds using initializer syntax. You could work around this as follows:

```
var fac = new Faculty {
     Name = txtTeachherName.Text, 
     Dept = cmbDepts.Items.CurrentItem.ToString(), 
     subInterest = new []{"HELLO", null, null, null}}
```

or after initialization:

```
fac.subInterest[0] = "HELLO";
```

Comment: Any better way to do it? I mean how the pros do?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `constructor` can also solve the problem like

```
public class Faculty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public string[] subInterest = new string[4];

    public Faculty(string name, string dept, string[] si)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Dept = dept;
        this.subInterest = si;
    }
}
```

Then instantiate the faculty class

```
string[] subinterest = new string[]{"reading","swmming",null,null};
var fac = new Faculty("dgdfgdfgfg","dfgdgfgdfg", subinterest);
```